# Generating all combinations of a list of strings with both parentheses and an operator being permuted, too

Tags: python, combinations, permutation, python-itertools

Let's say I have a list of the strings: 
`l = ['A','B','C','D']`

I know that to generate all combinations of these with replacement, `choose n`, that I would use the `itertools.combinations` library method to get them.

For example,
`list(combinations(l, 2))` would give me

`[['A','B'], ['A','C'],['A','D'],['B','C'],['B','D'],['C','D']]`

However, instead of brackets, I would like parentheses:

`['(A,B)', '(A,C)','(A,D)','(B,C)','(B,D)','(C,D)']`

Now, let's say I want to extend this and add in two operations for these `AND` and `OR`:

So that I would get `['(A','AND','B)', '(A','OR','B)',etc.]`

Extend that even further, to get nested parentheses in the case where `n=3`:

```
['((A','AND','B)', 'AND', 'C)', '((A','AND','B)', 'OR', 'C)', '((A','OR','B)', 'OR', 'C)', '((A','OR','B)', 'AND', 'C)', etc.]
```

With it ideally being of the form:

```
['((A AND B) AND C)', '((A AND B) OR C)', '((A OR B) OR C)', '((A OR B) AND C)', etc.]
```

So, in summary, I am choosing combinations a list `n` elements at a time, with permutations on operators ['AND', 'OR'] and adding nesting from the left.

I've done something similar in JavaScript, but there it was easier, since the user would construct the actual sentence. It was not created from a set of permutations and combinations.

Comment: What would be the desired output for `[['A','AND','B'], 'AND', 'C']` for example?

Comment: That is the desired output. I will edit and update my question accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `itertools.combinations` to pick operands from the given list, use `itertools.product` to produce combinations of operators, and use `itertools.product` again to produce all mixes of operands and operators, and use a `for` loop that keeps nesting lists according to the chosen operands and operators to build the desired output:

```
from itertools import combinations, product
def expressions(l, n):
    for (operations, *operands), operators in product(
            combinations(l, n), product(('AND', 'OR'), repeat=n - 1)):
        for operation in zip(operators, operands):
            operations = [operations, *operation]
        yield operations
```

so that `list(expressions(['A','B','C','D'], 3))` returns:

```
[[['A', 'AND', 'B'], 'AND', 'C'],
 [['A', 'AND', 'B'], 'OR', 'C'],
 [['A', 'OR', 'B'], 'AND', 'C'],
 [['A', 'OR', 'B'], 'OR', 'C'],
 [['A', 'AND', 'B'], 'AND', 'D'],
 [['A', 'AND', 'B'], 'OR', 'D'],
 [['A', 'OR', 'B'], 'AND', 'D'],
 [['A', 'OR', 'B'], 'OR', 'D'],
 [['A', 'AND', 'C'], 'AND', 'D'],
 [['A', 'AND', 'C'], 'OR', 'D'],
 [['A', 'OR', 'C'], 'AND', 'D'],
 [['A', 'OR', 'C'], 'OR', 'D'],
 [['B', 'AND', 'C'], 'AND', 'D'],
 [['B', 'AND', 'C'], 'OR', 'D'],
 [['B', 'OR', 'C'], 'AND', 'D'],
 [['B', 'OR', 'C'], 'OR', 'D']]
```

Comment: Cool! I like this, especially since I'm already using `itertools.` I'll give it a try.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Got it easily into my desired string form. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use recursion with a generator:

```
def op(d, n, _d, c = []):
  if _d == 1:
    yield c
  else:
    for i in d:
      if sum(isinstance(h, list) or h not in {'AND', 'OR'} for h in c) == n:
         yield from op(d, n, _d-1, c=[c, 'OR', i])
         yield from op(d, n, _d-1, c=[c, 'AND', i])
      else:
         if not c:
           yield from op(d, n, _d, c=[i])
         else:
           yield from op(d, n, _d, c=[*c, 'OR', i])
           yield from op(d, n, _d, c=[*c, 'AND', i])

result = list(op(['A','B','C','D'], 2, 2))
```

Output (first ten results):

```
[[['A', 'OR', 'A'], 'OR', 'A'], [['A', 'OR', 'A'], 'AND', 'A'], [['A', 'OR', 'A'], 'OR', 'B'], [['A', 'OR', 'A'], 'AND', 'B'], [['A', 'OR', 'A'], 'OR', 'C'], [['A', 'OR', 'A'], 'AND', 'C'], [['A', 'OR', 'A'], 'OR', 'D'], [['A', 'OR', 'A'], 'AND', 'D'], [['A', 'AND', 'A'], 'OR', 'A'], [['A', 'AND', 'A'], 'AND', 'A']]
```

This solution will enable you to control both the length and depth of each element in `result`. For instance, when generating to a depth of `4`:

```
result = list(op(['A','B','C','D'], 2, 4))
print(result[:10])
```

Output:

```
[[[[['A', 'OR', 'A'], 'OR', 'A'], 'OR', 'A'], 'OR', 'A'], [[[['A', 'OR', 'A'], 'OR', 'A'], 'OR', 'A'], 'AND', 'A'], [[[['A', 'OR', 'A'], 'OR', 'A'], 'OR', 'A'], 'OR', 'B'], [[[['A', 'OR', 'A'], 'OR', 'A'], 'OR', 'A'], 'AND', 'B'], [[[['A', 'OR', 'A'], 'OR', 'A'], 'OR', 'A'], 'OR', 'C'], [[[['A', 'OR', 'A'], 'OR', 'A'], 'OR', 'A'], 'AND', 'C'], [[[['A', 'OR', 'A'], 'OR', 'A'], 'OR', 'A'], 'OR', 'D'], [[[['A', 'OR', 'A'], 'OR', 'A'], 'OR', 'A'], 'AND', 'D'], [[[['A', 'OR', 'A'], 'OR', 'A'], 'AND', 'A'], 'OR', 'A'], [[[['A', 'OR', 'A'], 'OR', 'A'], 'AND', 'A'], 'AND', 'A']]
```

Comment: Nice, but I've already got a ton of recursion going on. I like the other method over this, especially since, as I noted, I'm already using `itertools.`